# How to specify an additional php file in Heroku PHP App?

Tags: php, heroku

I have a script.php file in my filesystem that is referred to by the JS file to make an ajax request after taking a user input. While it works on my local xampp, on deploying it to Heroku, console displays

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Is there a correct way to specify the script.php file?

Here's my file structure

```
index.php
main.js
main.css
script.php
composer.json
```

The json file is blank with a pair of curly braces.

Comment: Heroku is just a hosting system, it doesn't _evaluate_ anything unless you're writing anything specific inside your **package.json** scripts. Your question is very unclear, please describe what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: made the edit. Is it understandable now? The script.php makes a Twitter API call that is referred to by an ajax request. But the script.php isn't found. On going to the exact link /appurl/script.php, I see -1 being displayed.

Comment: I was talking about **composer.json** and not ***package.json***...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [500 error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) does not mean that script.php was not found but that this file had an error when executed.

By default, your app [is in production mode on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#production-and-development-modes), so won't see any PHP error.

You can [add a `.user.ini` file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#php-runtime-settings) to customize the remote `php.ini` file. In this file you will need to add these 2 lines, as you would do in a local configuration, to enable the remote development mode :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

It will surely help you understand what's the error which is surely linked with your API call settings.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had missed the twitteroauth folder, which I could see after the .ini file. Thanks